# How to find the path for the tweet textbox while using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I can't find the textbox for tweeting while using the auto software selenium.I have tried multiple class-names,xpaths in and around the textbox.

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")
twe=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/label/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div')
twe.send_keys(f"Happy Birthday")
but=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/span')
but.click()
```

Comment: Can you share the error trace?

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/label/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below code:

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")
twe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Tweet text']//span")))
twe.send_keys(f"Happy Birthday")
but = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[text()='Tweet'])[2]")))
but.click()
```

I changed the XPATH expressions and used `waits`. See if it works.

You will need the below imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: **AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'**

Comment: Check the updated answer. Add the import statements to your code.